# lexik jwt always returns bad cerdentials without creating a token

Tags: symfony, jsonresponse, lexikjwtauthbundle

I just started using `lexik-jwt` ! and the problem is that after running the cmd `:curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/login_check -d _username=johndoe -d _password=test` i always get this response `{"code":401,"message":"Bad credentials"}`

Comment: Do you have correctly configured an User provider ? If yes, a custom ? FOSUserBundle ? Please provide more informations.

Comment: I follwed the documentation in https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md ,  untel i reached the part when i have to test the token creation ! the curl cmd always returns 401 bad cerdentials , Idon't whether  to make any other customizations not mentioned in the official documentation like configuring a User provider or use FOSUserbundle to make it all work , thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an authentication system, users must [be loaded](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded) from somewhere.
To achieve this in Symfony, you need to configure a user provider.

There is a [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundleSandbox](https://github.com/slashfan/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundleSandbox/blob/master/app/config/security.yml) application that uses the built-in in-memory user provider.

Look at this one to have an idea of what you need.

Comment: For using it with the symfony built-in entity provider, see https://github.com/chalasr/lexik-jwt-authentication-sandbox